Unable to extract data span from a website
`I am able to extract house price data which is: $276,000
but I am not able to extract "Beds" or any other type of span data: example:
2
This is the script I am using:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

def extract_beds_from_url(url):
    beds_data = {'URL': url, 'Beds': 'N/A'}
    try:
        # Set up the WebDriver
        print("Setting up the WebDriver...")
        service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
        print("WebDriver set up successfully.")

        # Open the web page
        print(f"Opening URL: {url}")
        driver.get(url)
        print("URL opened successfully.")

        # Wait for the page to fully render
        time.sleep(10)

        # Extracting number of beds
        try:
            print("Attempting to find the beds element using CSS_SELECTOR...")
            beds_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[data-qa="beds"].item-detail-label')
            print("Beds element (CSS_SELECTOR) HTML content:", beds_element.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
            beds_data['Beds'] = beds_element.text if beds_element else 'N/A'
            print("Beds element found and extracted successfully using CSS_SELECTOR.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error while finding the beds element using CSS_SELECTOR: {e}")

        # Close the WebDriver
        print("Closing WebDriver...")
        driver.quit()
        print("WebDriver closed successfully.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred during the WebDriver setup or execution: {e}")

    return beds_data

# URL of the page to extract data from
page_url = 'https://portal.onehome.com/es-US/property/aotf~1075849001~SEFMIAMI?token=eyJPU04iOiJTRUZNSUFNSSIsInR5cGUiOiIxIiwiY29udGFjdGlkIjo5MjgxMjg5LCJzZXRrZXkiOiI3MzAiLCJlbWFpbCI6InRhYmlvMTk4NUBob3RtYWlsLmNvbSIsInJlc291cmNlaWQiOjAsImFnZW50aWQiOjEwOTc1LCJpc2RlbHRhIjpmYWxzZSwiVmlld01vZGUiOiIxIn0%3D&searchId=d198393a-22a6-33b5-a207-8db32bb8cf89'

# Extract beds from the URL
beds_data = extract_beds_from_url(page_url)

# Print the extracted data
print("Extracted Data:")
print(f"URL: {beds_data['URL']}")
print(f"Beds: {beds_data['Beds']}")

I am expecting to get Beds printed but it is coming empty.

Did you use ChatGPT or another AI to generate the code above?

Unfortunately yes. To understand some workflows, I wasn't aware of this site policy regarding AI, so it's fare enough if I get punished for it. Apologize in advance.

imho this will seriously impede your learning and capacity to write meaningful code. I suggest you try and learn to write the code yourself, by breaking the problem into small, easy to understand steps, i.e. get one element, then get another, and so on.

I will. Thanks a lot Barry.

How about accessing the underlying API directly?
The code below is long but it can be trimmed down significantly. The query value in json_data is GraphQL and specifies all of the fields requested from the API. You can retain just the ones that you want.
I'm dumping the API response to a JSON file. If you search that file for "Bed" you should find this:
"BedroomsTotal": 2.0,

import requests
import json

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.EuvRAVmjh2H4b_oGr9vfkmPF37UpQfmTAJxa8-Fmbqk',
}

json_data = {
    'operationName': 'ListingById',
    'variables': {
        'suppressEvent': False,
        'listingId': 'aotf~1075849001~SEFMIAMI',
        'groupId': '',
    },
    'query': """
query ListingById($listingId: String!, $groupId: String!, $savedSearchId: String, $suppressEvent: Boolean = true) {
  listingDetail(listingId: $listingId, groupId: $groupId, savedSearchId: $savedSearchId, suppressEvent: $suppressEvent) {
    id
    createdAt
    hideWhenUnauth
    property {
      ...PropertyInfoFields
      __typename
    }
    media {
      LongDescription
      LongDescription_es_US
      LongDescription_en_CA
      LongDescription_fr_CA
      ShortDescription
      ImageOf
      MediaType
      Order
      Image {
        Thumbnail {
          ...imageDetails
          __typename
        }
        Medium {
          ...imageDetails
          __typename
        }
        Large {
          ...imageDetails
          __typename
        }
        __typename
      }
      __typename
    }
    openHouse {
      OpenHouseDate
      OpenHouseEndTime
      OpenHouseStartTime
      OpenHouseStatus
      OpenHouseType
      OpenHouseLiveStreamURL
      Refreshments
      __typename
    }
    rooms {
      RoomType
      RoomLevel
      RoomDimensions
      RoomLength
      RoomWidth
      RoomFeatures
      RoomFlooring
      RoomDescription
      __typename
    }
    unitType {
      UnitTypeActualRent
      UnitTypeActualRentRange
      UnitTypeBedsTotal
      UnitTypeBathsTotal
      UnitTypeUnitsTotal
      UnitTypeDescription
      UnitTypeArea
      UnitTypeTotalRent
      __typename
    }
    customProperty {
      FIPSCode
      LivingAreaRange
      LivingAreaRangeUnits
      LotSizeRange
      BelowGradeFinishedAreaRange
      BelowGradeUnfinishedAreaRange
      AboveGradeFinishedAreaRange
      AboveGradeUnfinishedAreaRange
      BuildingAreaTotalRange
      PropertyKey
      LeaseAmountPerArea
      LeaseAmountPerAreaUnit
      ListingKey
      ListingId
      LandTenure
      SourceSupplementPublicCount
      TransactionDeskUrl
      BrightDocumentsUrl
      PublicRemarks_en_CA
      PublicRemarks_es_US
      PublicRemarks_fr_CA
      PublicRemarks_lang2
      PublicRemarks_lang3
      Directions_es_US
      Directions_en_CA
      Directions_en_EG
      Directions_fr_CA
      BoatDockYN
      NumberOfBoatDocks
      BoatDockHeight
      BoatSlipYN
      NumberOfBoatSlips
      BoatDockAccommodates
      BoatDockSlipFeatures
      BoatDockSlipDescription
      MonthlyRate
      BelowGradeBedrooms
      AboveGradeBedrooms
      OffersDescription
      OffersReviewDate
      ThirdPartyIntegrationType
      CustomFields {
        MileMarker
        MileMarkerArea
        LakeDepthFeet
        RoadBetweenWaterfrontAndHomeYN
        LakeBottomType
        ElevationHighPointWaterfrontFeet
        WaterfrontSlopeType
        ChainName
        ChainAcres
        DNRLakeIDNumber
        DNRLakeClass
        RentalAvailability
        MinimumRentalPeriod
        FurnishedAnnualPrice
        FurnishedOffseasonPrice
        UnfurnishedAnnualPrice
        UnfurnishedOffseasonPrice
        UnfurnishedSeasonalPrice
        FurnishedSeasonalPrice
        ResortFee
        ResortFeePer
        TransferTax
        DeedRestricted
        AdditionalMembershipAvailableYN
        NumberOfPets
        MaxPetWeight
        BasementPercentFinished
        AssociationFeeRequirement
        AssociationFeeComments
        AssociationApprovalRequiredYN
        OtherFeesAmount
        PetRestrictions
        PetFeeNonRefundable
        MinimumLease
        AssociationApprovalFee
        MontlyMaintAmtAdditionToHOA
        PetSize
        PetDepositFee
        AdditionalPetFees
        TotalAvailSqFt
        LeasedPricePerSqFt
        GarageSqft
        SqFtTotalPropertyHLA
        FeeOptions
        FeePurchase
        Deposit
        PetRefund
        PetDeposit
        PerPetYN
        SpecialLevyYN
        UtilityCostsLease
        ExpensesforYearEndingMMYY
        LaundryOtherIncome
        HydroCostLease
        AnnualDebtService
        AnnualGrossIncomeComment
        GrossOperatingIncome
        NetOperatingIncomeComments
        NetOperIncomeMultiNOI
        OtherCosts
        OtherCostsComments
        OtherIncomeOTHR
        TotalOperatExpPct
        SchedRentalIncomeSRI
        SecurityExpense
        VacancyLossAmount
        VacancyLossRatioVL
        CashFlowAmount
        __typename
      }
      WaterAccessYN
      LakeSize
      RentSpreeURL
      RentSpreeYN
      AvailabilityType
      Restrictions
      FractionalShare
      OriginatingSystemPropertyTaxKey
      RentalBeastLink
      AdditionalFeeDescription
      AdditionalFee
      OtherExpense
      __typename
    }
    propertyLevel {
      LevelType
      LevelBedsTotal
      LevelBathroomsFull
      LevelBathroomsHalf
      __typename
    }
    notes {
      notes {
        note
        timestamp
        __typename
      }
      __typename
    }
    sourceMedia {
      ...SourceMediaFields
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
}

fragment PropertyInfoFields on Property {
  OriginatingSystemKey
  StreetNumber
  StreetAdditionalInfo
  StreetDirPrefix
  StreetName
  StreetSuffix
  StreetDirSuffix
  UnitNumber
  City
  PostalCity
  StateOrProvince
  PostalCode
  PostalCodePlus4
  InternetAddressDisplayYN
  VirtualTourURLUnbranded
  VirtualTourURLUnbranded2
  VirtualTourURLUnbranded3
  BedroomsTotal
  BathroomsTotalInteger
  LivingArea
  LivingAreaUnits
  LivingAreaTotal
  PublicRemarks
  YearBuilt
  LotSizeArea
  LotSizeUnits
  ParkingTotal
  HeatingYN
  Heating
  CoolingYN
  Cooling
  AssociationFee
  AssociationFeeFrequency
  AssociationFee2
  AssociationFee2Frequency
  PoolPrivateYN
  PoolFeatures
  PetsAllowed
  LeaseTerm
  CountyOrParish
  BathroomsFull
  BathroomsThreeQuarter
  BathroomsHalf
  BathroomsOneQuarter
  BathroomsPartial
  BuildingAreaTotal
  BuildingAreaUnits
  Levels
  Stories
  InteriorFeatures
  BasementYN
  Basement
  Flooring
  SecurityFeatures
  WindowFeatures
  FireplaceYN
  FireplaceFeatures
  FireplacesTotal
  Appliances
  AccessibilityFeatures
  PropertyType
  ArchitecturalStyle
  Ownership
  DirectionFaces
  LotSizeDimensions
  LotFeatures
  ParkingFeatures
  CarportYN
  CarportSpaces
  GarageYN
  GarageSpaces
  AttachedGarageYN
  CoveredSpaces
  ExteriorFeatures
  WaterfrontYN
  WaterfrontFeatures
  WaterBodyName
  Fencing
  PatioAndPorchFeatures
  RoadFrontageType
  RoadSurfaceType
  Topography
  ViewYN
  View
  GreenEnergyEfficient
  LaundryFeatures
  Sewer
  WaterSource
  Utilities
  ConstructionMaterials
  YearBuiltEffective
  Roof
  HomeWarrantyYN
  BodyType
  FoundationDetails
  PropertyAttachedYN
  AssociationYN
  AssociationName
  AssociationName2
  SeniorCommunityYN
  AssociationAmenities
  AssociationFeeIncludes
  RentControlYN
  BuildingName
  StoriesTotal
  ElementarySchoolDistrict
  ElementarySchool
  MiddleOrJuniorSchoolDistrict
  MiddleOrJuniorSchool
  HighSchoolDistrict
  HighSchool
  ListingId
  CLIP
  ListPrice
  Inclusions
  Exclusions
  Directions
  NumberOfUnitsTotal
  OtherStructures
  CurrentUse
  PossibleUse
  DevelopmentStatus
  ElectricOnPropertyYN
  GrossIncome
  HorseAmenities
  LandLeaseAmount
  LandLeaseAmountFrequency
  LeaseAmount
  LeaseAmountFrequency
  LeaseConsideredYN
  ListingTerms
  NetOperatingIncome
  NumberOfBuildings
  NumberOfUnitsInCommunity
  NumberOfUnitsVacant
  OperatingExpense
  SpaYN
  SpaFeatures
  Zoning
  ZoningDescription
  ParcelNumber
  TaxAssessedValue
  TaxYear
  Contingency
  TaxAnnualAmount
  AvailabilityDate
  Furnished
  RentIncludes
  TenantPays
  OwnerPays
  Township
  SubdivisionName
  CommunityFeatures
  BusinessName
  BusinessType
  YearEstablished
  LeaseRenewalOptionYN
  MajorChangeType
  SpecialListingConditions
  NewConstructionYN
  Latitude
  Longitude
  MajorChangeTimestamp
  PropertySubType
  StructureType
  PropertyCondition
  ClosePrice
  PreviousListPrice
  DprLink
  RatePlugLink
  StandardStatus
  AboveGradeFinishedArea
  AboveGradeFinishedAreaUnits
  BelowGradeFinishedArea
  BelowGradeFinishedAreaUnits
  DaysOnMarket
  CloseDate
  EntryLevel
  BuilderName
  RoadResponsibility
  Possession
  BuyerFinancing
  MLSAreaMinor
  TaxLegalDescription
  ActivationDate
  ListOfficeName
  CoListOfficeName
  ListOfficeEmail
  CoListOfficeEmail
  ListOfficePhone
  CoListOfficePhone
  BuyerAgencyCompensation
  BuyerAgencyCompensationType
  BuyerBrokerageCompensation
  BuyerBrokerageCompensationType
  MLSAreaMajor
  OriginatingSystemName
  CommonInterest
  FrontageLength
  FrontageType
  FoundationArea
  AttributionContact
  PrivateRemarks
  ShowingInstructions
  ShowingRequirements
  LockBoxType
  LockBoxLocation
  OwnerName
  OwnerPhone
  ShowingContactName
  ShowingContactPhone
  SubAgencyCompensationType
  SubAgencyCompensation
  TransactionBrokerCompensationType
  TransactionBrokerCompensation
  DualVariableCompensationYN
  ListAgentStateLicense
  ListingAgreement
  ListingContractDate
  ExpirationDate
  OriginalListPrice
  ListAgentFullName
  ListAgentMobilePhone
  ListAgentEmail
  ListAgentOfficePhone
  ListAgentMlsId
  PendingTimestamp
  SourceSystemKey
  CrossStreet
  PermissionPrivate
  LeaseExpiration
  CityRegion
  OtherParking
  TotalActualRent
  TrashExpense
  UtilitiesExpense
  ElectricExpense
  InsuranceExpense
  GardenerExpense
  MaintenanceExpense
  ManagerExpense
  NetOperatingIncome
  OperatingExpenseIncludes
  CableTvExpense
  SuppliesExpense
  WaterSewerExpense
  DocumentsAvailable
  VacancyAllowanceRate
  BuildingFeatures
  __typename
}

fragment imageDetails on Image {
  mediaUrl
  width
  height
  size
  __typename
}

fragment SourceMediaFields on SourceMedia {
  MediaObjectID
  LongDescription
  ShortDescription
  sourceMediaLink
  ImageOf
  __typename
}
""",
}

response = requests.post('https://services.onehome.com/graphql?ListingById', headers=headers, json=json_data)

print(response.text)

with open("results.json", "wt") as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))


Thanks a lot datawookie. I will give it a try.
